# How to remove Set elements (and associated components) from a pyomo model?

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo

I am trying to remove elements from a pyomo Set after a model has been created, in order to explore a smaller-sized optimization problem instance.  In short, my question is: **How can one ensure the model's integrity after removing a Set element?**

My approach has been to loop through the Param, Var, Constraint, and Expression components that may be indexed by the Set that changed.  (It's pretty cumbersome for a large model, but not sure how else to do it!)

Errors are raised when calling solve() after removing set elements, and in my attempts to remedy the situation, I have been trying to remove the Param components with index values of the removed Set elements.

*As each component is looped over, the components that have index keys equal to that Set element's value are removed.  It doesn't seem to work for pyo.Param components though, because when you try to index them, the actual value is returned instead of the component.  So 'del' doesn't work.... and passing an entirely new dictionary (which would require restructuring outside of pyomo) won't work unless it is mutable.  Perhaps it needs to be mutable?*

Here is a minimal example...  (with two sets, two parameters, and one variable)

```py
# --- Build a model ---
my_model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
my_model.A = pyo.Set(initialize=['a1', 'a2'])
my_model.B = pyo.Set(initialize=['b1', 'b2'])
my_model.C = pyo.Set(initialize=[('a1', 'b1'), ('a2', 'b1'), ('a2', 'b2')], within=my_model.A*my_model.B)
my_model.param1 = pyo.Param(my_model.A, initialize={'a1': 5, 'a2': 9})
my_model.param2 = pyo.Param(my_model.B, initialize={'b1': 1, 'b2': 2})
my_model.x = pyo.Var(my_model.A, my_model.B, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)
def constraint_rule(m, a):
    temp = sum([(m.param1[a] * m.x[a, b]) 
                for b in m.B])
    return 5, temp, None
my_model.constraint = pyo.Constraint(my_model.A, rule=constraint_rule)
def objective_rule(m):
    return sum([(m.param1[a] * m.param2[b] * m.x[a, b]) 
                for a in m.A 
                for b in m.B])
my_model.objective_expr = pyo.Expression(rule=objective_rule)
my_model.objective = pyo.Objective(rule=lambda m: m.component('objective_expr'), sense=pyo.minimize)

# --- Now let's remove an element ('a2') from set1 ---

# --- First, hold on to data, so that we're not later attempting to change components while iterating over them inside loops ---
temp_A = my_model.A.data().copy()
temp_B = my_model.B.data().copy()
temp_param1_dict = {k: v for k, v in my_model.param1.items()}
temp_x_list = [k for k in my_model.x.items()].copy()

# --- Do the removals ---
element_to_remove = 'a2'
for k in temp_A:
    if k == element_to_remove:
        my_model.A.remove(k)
for k in list(temp_param1_dict):
    if k == element_to_remove:
        del my_model.param1[k] 
for k, v in temp_x_list:
    if k[0] == element_to_remove:
        del my_model.x[k]

# --- Reconstruct the associated expressions ---
my_model.objective_expr.reconstruct()
my_model.constraint.reconstruct()

# --- Solve ---
results = pyo.SolverFactory('ipopt').solve(my_model, tee=True)
```

On my setup (pyomo=5.6.2), the above code throws the exception:

```py
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_component'
```

...for the line "del my_model.param1[k]"

However, if I just comment out the part that removes the Param, then I get two other errors (I think during preprocessing):

```py
KeyError: 90706423712
```

```py
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getname'
```

(Note: This is basically a follow-up to this previous question: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/pyomo-forum/WEySR4eJ4-A/Fyas8sGcAQAJ)

Thanks for any insight you can provide!